# Azure Logic Apps - Alerts Notification for Failures

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that runs every three days, it is requested that a notification (email/SMS) is sent when one of the steps fails in the app. I was thinking the best way to accomplish  this is to query the logs as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-unified-log
As I look through the logs I am not seeing my activity either a success or failure.  Can someone point me in the direction to have the events stored and queried. I do have the log analytic workspace connected to the logic app.

I have executed the logic app trigger with both successful and failures outcomes. These events are not showing up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps-oms#install-logic-apps-management-solution) to add Logic Apps Management to your log analytic workspace. This solution provides you a summary of overall health of your Logic Apps, with options to drill into details and to troubleshoot unexpected behavior patterns.

Cause you already have a workspace, you just need to add Logic Apps Management. With this you will be able to see the runs details.

[image]

Also you could query logs with log explorer. It's a [Kusto query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-queries).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to get notifications sent from logic apps is to just wrap all of the logic in a "scope" control. Then after that add a "notification" step that runs on error of the scope. Imagine an Email or text message action at the end of it. 
This gives you some flexibility on who needs to be notified. Like if you had an after-hours support vs normal business hours.

You could also use the Alerts feature which can send out notifications on failures.
[image]